# how can we attach extra volume without editing the running deployment?

Tags: kubernetes, persistent-volumes, kubernetes-pvc

We have deployments like below which is running with the single volume. now we need to attach extra volume to the same.

how can we achieve this without editing the running deployment.

Ex:

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: httpd-deployment
  namespace: httpd-test
  labels:
    app: httpd_app
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: httpd_app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: httpd_app
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: httpd-container
        image: httpd:latest
        ports:
         - containerPort: 80
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: "/data/test"
          name: my-pv-storage
      volumes:
      - name: my-pv-storage
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: my-pv-claim
```

We have tried with dynamic provisioning , and also have tried with the sed command in shell script .

Answer (score 1):

Short answer - you can't. When you change volumes and volume mounts - you change pod definition, which forces pod recreation. The other reason for that, is that type of PV used actually matters in scheduling. Imagine if you had a pod, that required a new RWO Volume, also used by some other pod. K8s docs define this as

> ReadWriteOnce – the volume can be mounted as read-write by a single node

So if both of your pods are located on different nodes - one of them should be recreated, because otherwise one of them won't be able to access this PV at all.

You should treat pod recreation as a normal part of lifecycle of your application, scale it if possible, so rollout restart won't affect your users at all.